# None-unique pandas dataframe index created using cur.fetch_pandas_all() after loading data from Snowflake

Tags: pandas, snowflake-connector

I used the code below to load data from Snowflake to Pandas dataframe for a long time, until I updated snowflake-connector-python==2.7.0 and pyarrow==5.0.0

```py
    ctx = connector.connect(
        user=user,
        password=pwd,
        account="***.eu-central-1",
        warehouse="***",
        database="***",
    )

    cur = ctx.cursor()

    cur.execute(data_sql)

    # Issue occurs here
    long_data_df = cur.fetch_pandas_all()
```

Everything worked as expected, but after the update to mentioned versions, dataframe is generated with non-unique dataframe index.

| index | colA |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | val1 |
| 0 | val2 |
| 0 | val3 |
| 1 | val4 |

with pyarrow==3.0.0 and snowflake-connector-python==2.4.6 (I am not sure in what version this change/bug occured), the dataframe looked like below

| index | colA |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | val1 |
| 2 | val2 |
| 3 | val3 |
| 4 | val4 |

The trouble occurs when you try to do pd.concat dataframe with non-unique index, it fails with `pandas.errors.InvalidIndexError: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects`

Comment: Looks like a bug in the Snowflake connector connector which has hopefully been fixed in this PR (yet to be included in new release though). https://github.com/snowflakedb/snowflake-connector-python/pull/1068

Answer (score 0):

We didn't want to downgrade pyarrow and snowflake-connector-python packages, we solved it by reseting index in pandas dataframe by adding

```py
long_data_df = long_data_df.reset_index(drop=True)
```